# × TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, antd, daterangepicker

```
const onChangeTourSeasonalDates = (task,dateStrings) => {
// console.log("Seasosnal dates",dates[0]._d)
const formState = [{ index: task.index, startRange: dateStrings[0], endRange: 
dateStrings[1] }];

const newTourSeasonalDate = state.tourSeasonalDates.map(item => {
  return item.index === formState.index ? formState : item;
});
console.log('task is task ', newTourSeasonalDate);

setState({ ...state, tourSeasonalDates: { ...state.tourSeasonalDates, 
 newTourSeasonalDate } });
 };

 {state.tourSeasonalDates.map(task => (
              <DateRangeComponent
                onChange={()=>onChangeTourSeasonalDates(task)}
                onClickMinusButton={() => deleteTourSeasonalDatesRow(task)}
                key={task.index}
              />
            ))}
```

//I was trying to match the index of each row daterangepicker and pass each range data in the state. Here i have daterangecomponent which consist of antd Rangepicker in which i am getting error while using onChange. Since i was trying to pass task index in onchange so that it will match according to the index in each row. Also dataStrings is default onChangePicker for getting date range. Here i want to get the final output as tourSeasonalDates:[{
index: task.index, startRange: dateStrings[0], endRange:
dateStrings[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86qsY.jpg)}
,
index: task.index, startRange: dateStrings[0], endRange:
dateStrings[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86qsY.jpg)]

in which each object we get according to the selected date range in row.

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Your function onChangeTourSeasonalDates accept two parameters, but you are only giving one when calling it, your "dateStrings" is undefined.
Hence why JS cannot read the property [0]

Comment: Actually i was not able to pass default dateString value in onChange function. Later figured out that and the problem is solved. Thank your time and help anyway.